# How can I resolve this issue in mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Error in Processing Request
Error code: 403
Error text: Forbidden

This kind of error pops up when i am trying to do anything that requires ajax in phpmyadmin.

[This is a snapshot of the error displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58nCA.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What does the webserver error log show?

Answer (score 1):

The installation of Mod Security can be one of the causes of this problem. To disable Mod Security in phpMyAdmin and add SecRuleEngine Off, locate phpmyadmin.conf.
Additionally, you can secure your phpMyAdmin installation by doing it the other way.

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
SecRuleEngine Off
....
</Directory>
```

Comment: I already added this snapshot to my httpd phpMyAdmin configuration but the problem was not resolved.